# VIm Grep on raspberry pi

Tags: vim, raspberry-pi

i want to grep search with vim editor on raspberry pi, Rasbian.

in windows, i usually use findstr and command like this

```
grep -s xxxx *.c
```

how do i grep search with vim editor on os Rasbian?

Comment: https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/linux-grep-command-usage-examples/ this site should help you some

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you wanna grep, just without leaving Vim, you can use [`:!cmd`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3A%21cmd) to run `grep` as an external command: `:!grep xxx *.c`
- Vim has [`:grep`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Agrep); it also uses the external `grep` (or whatever is configured in `'grepprg'`), but parses the results and presents them in the [`quickfix`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#quickfix) list, which allows you to quickly navigate results inside Vim.
- If you don't have / don't want to use external `grep`, there's also the [`:vimgrep`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Avimgrep) variant. You have to use Vim's regular expression syntax, and it'll be slower because files are loaded into Vim.
- Within a buffer, there are many alternatives, like [`:global`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Aglobal) or [`:ilist`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/tagsrch.txt.html#%3Ailist). With [`:bufdo`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Abufdo), you can run them on all opened buffers.